# AngularJS stops working as soon as I include a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and I'm running into a road block.   As soon as I include a controller on my form tag, any remaining angular JS stops functioning.

eg:

```
start {{ 1 + 1 }}
<form id="contact-form" ng-controller="messagingController">
</form>
end {{ 1 + 1 }}
```

What I will see is:

```
start 2
end {{ 1 + 1 }}
```

I have ng-app on the body tag.
I have angular script included at the top of my page.
I include a js for the controller

If you need to see the entire source, just go to http://tatmanblue.com/.  Scroll to the bottom.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thnx
Matt

Comment: do you get errors in console?

Comment: try to change your ng-app declaration to ng-app="messagingForm"

Comment: how do I check the console for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the body tag you need to write the module name with ng-app

```
<body ng-app="messagingForm" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

please see here https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=messagingController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined which means there is no function messagingController, 
You missed js for controller